# Can't add/modify values at a variable in 2 diferentes files

Tags: kotlin

I need help setting and getting values from other variables in differents files (.kt files)

So i have this code:

File main.kt:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    test().teste.add("Tesasdfasdf")
    println(test().variable)
}
```

File test.kt:

```
class test {
    public var variable = ArrayList<String>()
}
```

Output:
`[]`

Can someone help me with that?

Beginner to kotlin! Thanks for every help! <3

Comment: in the second line you're creating a new instance of your "test" class by using `test()`. This instance is different from the one you create in the line above, that's why you're seeing an empty list in output. Try assigning the first instance to a variable: `val myInstance = test()` and reuse that variable for the addition and to print the result

Comment: Oh got it, but imagine i want to set a value from other file (main.kt) to that variable then on the other file (test.kt) i want to get that value?

Comment: Kotlin is an object oriented language which means objects can interact with other objects. If you want to change the state of object A from within object B you can obviously do that, but you need object B to have a reference to the very same object A that you want to update

Comment: I don't see what you want to do, in the case you want to transfer things, probably create a singleton which can be shared across the whole application through the runtime. Otherwise maybe you need to have a reference of the object somehow.